# Can 'inf' be assigned to a variable like regular numeric values in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, divide-by-zero

When I wrote the following code, instead of causing runtime error, it outputs 'inf'. Now, is there any way to assign this value ('inf') to a variable, like regular numeric values? How to check if a division yields 'inf'?

```
#include<iostream>    

int main(){
    double a = 1, b = 0;
    std::cout << a / b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The behaviour of floating point division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926763/the-behaviour-of-floating-point-division-by-zero)

Comment: Perhaps [HUGE_VAL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/HUGE_VAL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ does not require implementations to support infinity or division by zero. Many implementations will, as many implementations use IEEE 754 formats even if they do not fully support IEEE 754 semantics.

**When you want to use infinity as a value** (that is, you want to refer to infinity in source code), you should not generate it by dividing by zero. Instead, include `<limits>` and use [`std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity) with `T` specified as `double`.

> Returns the special value "positive infinity", as represented by the floating-point type T. Only meaningful if [`std::numeric_limits< T >::has_infinity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_infinity)`== true`.

(You may also see code that includes `<cmath>` and uses [`INFINITY`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/INFINITY), which are inherited from C.)

**When you want to check** if a number is finite, include `<cmath>` and use [`std::isfinite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite). Note that computations with infinite values tend to ultimately produce `NaN`s, and `std::isfinite(x)` is generally more convenient than `!std::isinf(x) && !std::isnan(x)`.

**A final warning in case you are using unsafe compiler flags**: In case you use, e.g., GCC's [`-ffinite-math-only`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-ffinite-math-only) (included in [`-ffast-math`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-ffast-math)) then [`std::isfinite` does not work](https://godbolt.org/g/xj9Xjx).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be I can:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    double a = 1, b = 0, c = 1/0.0;
    std::cout << a / b << endl;
    if (a / b == c) std::cout << "Yes you can.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should 'inf' be equal to 1?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's a typo.