# C - Printf doesn't output the expected result

Tags: c, printf, output

I'm a University student and I'm trying to verify different printf output through the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=3,j=0;
    float x=5,y;
    printf("1: %d\n", i);  
    printf("2: %d\n", i/j);
    printf("3: %d\n", i*i);
    printf("4: i = \n");   
    i=i + j;               
    printf("6: %f\n", x/y);
    printf("7: x = %f\n"); 
    printf("8: %d\n", i/2);
    printf("9: %f", x/2) ; 
    return 0;
}
```

In the execution phase, after the first output `printf("1: %d\n", i);`, I don't get anything in the terminal.
Any idea? (no compiling error)

Comment: You are attempting division by zero.

Comment: @Gabriele Berselli The variable y was not initialized.

Comment: What output do you *expect* to get for each line?

Comment: There is no "the expected result" for the operation `3/0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i / j` is `3 / 0`, and integer division by 0 in C is Undefined Behavior, which means that literally anything can happen. In your case, "literally anything" meant "[go back in time](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) and make the previous `printf` not work, then crash" (this actually happened due to how buffering works, but that's just an implementation detail).

Comment: As a minor nit, its not integer division by zero that's undefined behaviour, but having the right operand of `/` be 0 (anywhere, for any purpose) that's UB.

Comment: @kopecs Isn't `float f = 1.5 / 0` well-defined as infinity?

Comment: From C99 (the 2007 working copy at least) 6.5.5.5: "The result of the `/` operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the result of the `%` operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined."

(I'll admit, I'm a bit surprised it isn't defined for floating point numbers, but I don't think the standard necessitates IEEE 754 or equivalent).

Comment: @kopecs In "pure" C99 you'd be right, but Annex F overrides that: [The behaviour of floating point division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42926763/7509065)

Comment: and it seems that may be why the standard appeared to conflict with my common sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What did you expect to get for the line `printf("2: %d\n", i/j);`  when `i = 3` and `j = 0`?

Do you see a reason why your program might interrupt at that point?

### Followup questions:

What output do you expect from these lines?
***Explain why for each one!***

```
printf("6: %f\n", x/y);
printf("7: x = %f\n"); 
printf("9: %f", x/2) ;
```

---

Since you provided your answers, You're wrong on the first two expectations.

```
printf("6: %f\n", x/y); <-- "y" as you said is not declared, so I suppose to have a random float number.
```

`y` is ***declared***, but it is not initialized.
Division by an uninitialized value, *in practice* will produce an unknown value. 
But by the spec, it is Undefined Behavior, and anything can happen.

---

```
printf("7: x = %f\n"); <-- this is one other question, because the terminal gives me a random value either.
```

Because you did not provide a parameter to go into the `%f` slot, it is undefined behavior, and you might get Nasal Demons.

Comment: printf("6: %f\n", x/y); <-- "y" as you said is not declared, so I suppose to have a random float number.
printf("7: x = %f\n");  <-- this is one other question, because the terminal gives me a random value either.
printf("9: %f", x/2) ; <-- 2.500000