# Why do i get "-inf" instead of the typed cout in if

Tags: c++

The question is to determine if the equation a*x+b=0 has 1 solution, and write it, if it has 0 solutions write no solutions and if it has infinite solutions type infinite solutions

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a,b,x;
    cin>>a>>b;
    x=-b/a;
    if(x!=0)
        cout<<x<<endl;
    else if(a==0)
        cout<<"no solution"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"infinite solutions"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Its supposed to write "no solutions" but instead it says -inf

Comment: Its doing what you asked, -inf is not 0 so the if goes through. if you wanted it to write no solutions because a == 0 then you should check for that first. (I disagree with the duplicate fwiw)

Comment: The duplicate is good background information, but not _especially_ directly relevant to this question.

Comment: The duplicate was "[is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)"  I have reopened this so the question may be better addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checks are in the wrong order. Since you are not specifying your input, my assumption is:

```
a=0;
b=1; // Or any other number, for that matter
```

This means, for your input, you are dividing `-1` by `0` which is `-inf` (Mathematically incorrect, but floating point numbers (sometimes) work that way, see [The behaviour of floating point division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926763/the-behaviour-of-floating-point-division-by-zero))

If-else chains are evaluated from top to bottom, stopping at the first condition evaluating to `true`.

As you are checking `x!=0` first and `-inf` is not equal to `0`, you just get the output of `-inf`.

To ensure you catch the division by zero case, you need to check for that first.

Your code would look like this then:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a,b,x;
    cin>>a>>b;
    x=-b/a;
    if(a==0)
        cout<<"no solution"<<endl;
    else if(x!=0)
        cout<<x<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"infinite solutions"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```