# How ARM Compilers Handle Run Time Errors?

Tags: exception, arm, cortex-m, divide-by-zero

I am trying to generate a run time error such as divide by zero in ARM Cortex M3. I don't know why when I generate divide by zero error system works correctly. However value seems "Infinity"

[image]

Does ARM gcc compilers handle these kind of UsageFault errors? I did not implement hardware exception handler yet like Usage Fault, Bus Fault or Mem Manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to [x86](/questions/tagged/x86), no exception is thrown for [arm](/questions/tagged/arm) if an integer division by zero takes place. There is simply returned `0` as the result

**Edit:** This only applies to the Cortex-A series. As Jose noted, there is a control register for integer division in the Cortex-M series, as in the case of Floating-point division described in the following. See the link in his answer.

---

For floating point operations, the *Floating-point Control Register* (`FPSCR` for aarch32 or `FPCR` for aarch64) is decisive for whether an exception is thrown. If the corresponding bit is set there, an exception is thrown, otherwise only a flag in the *Floating-Point Status Register* (`FPSCR` in aarch32 or `FPSR` in aarch64) is set which then indicates the error. This registers can be set via `msr` and read via `mrs`.

If no exception is thrown, there are the following rules:

- `infinity` divided `infinity` is `NaN`
- `zero` divided `zero` is `NaN`
- Anything other divided `infinity` is `±zero`
- Anything other divided `zero` in `±infinity` (sign according to the dividend,
  this is the case you got in your screenshot)
- `infinity` divided anything other is `±infinity`
- `zero` divided anything other is `±zero`

See the pseudocode of `FDIV` in *ARM a64 instruction set architecture*.

---

References:

- [FPCR](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100446/0100/aarch64-register-descriptions/fpcr--floating-point-control-register) and [FPSR](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100446/0100/aarch64-register-descriptions/fpsr--floating-point-status-register) in aarch64
- [FPSCR](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100446/0100/aarch32-register-descriptions/fpscr--floating-point-status-and-control-register?lang=en) in aarch32
- [ARM a64 instruction set architecture](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0596/a/DDI_0596_ARM_a64_instruction_set_architecture.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the architecture the behaviour is different. ARMv6-M doesn't include a divide instruction so it's the software the one to manage this situation (or the compiler, from the [C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004095/division-by-zero-undefined-behavior-or-implementation-defined-in-c-and-or-c) point of view, it is UB).

On [Cortex M3](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/divide-and-conquer) (ARMv7-M) things are different, there is an [UsageFault](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0552/a/cortex-m3-peripherals/system-control-block/configurable-fault-status-register?lang=en) exception to manage DIVBY0 situations.